# Can I capture the current/all tabs URL with JavaScript/jQuery or would I need to make a plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, url, google-chrome

I want to be able to capture the current [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) and/or the URL of all open tabs.

Can I do this in JavaScript or [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) or am I going to need a plugin in FireFox/Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the other posters said, you can’t grab URLs of tabs besides the current one with standard JavaScript. But you can with Firefox / Google Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 6):

> "capture (...) URL of all open tabs."

Why don't you ask Chrome for the stored passwords while you are at it?

The answer is: **No, you can't.**
It would be a serious privacy issue if that was remotely possible.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow question *[Get current URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192)* is showing how to get the current URL.

But I am not sure about getting the URL for all tabs.