# Send text to an already-open WhatsApp on a PC browser

Tags: javascript, browser, whatsapp

I'm using some JavaScript code to enable a PC user to send text to WhatsApp friends:

`window.open("https://wa.me/?text=" + encodeURIComponent("Hello, world!"));`

It does work, however, even if there's already a WhatsApp tab open - it opens a **new** one (forcing the user to reconnect to WhatsApp on a new tab).

Is there any option to use an already-open WhatsApp tab, if there is one?

Comment: I think you can't because JavaScript can't check all the other tabs URLs, it would be a [great security problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3296416/22152755) however it's possible in [Firefox/Chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11114395/22152755).

Answer (score 0):

Not possible unless you're building a chrome extension. You might want to look into this [Retrieving which tabs are open in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915370/retrieving-which-tabs-are-open-in-chrome)